# How to Get Selected Sheet Names in Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to get names of the selected sheets in Excel. I have 4-5 worksheets in my excel file. User is supposed to select two of them and then my application scans specific columns and compare values. However I could not find a way in C# to get names of the worksheets when user selects more than one sheet. User can also delete these selected worksheets via the application. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using VSTO:

```cs
var sheets = Application.ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets;

var names = new List<string>();
foreach (Excel.Worksheet sh in sheets)
{
  names.Add(sh.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @rkrahl. This was just I was looking for. I had not notice the ActiveWindow reference.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use Spreadsheetgear: [Link to Spreadsheetgear website](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/)

This is the easiest solution to manipulating Excel workbooks I tryed. But quite expensive.

Comment: Thank you for your mentioning @ForeverSmiling, however I do not have a budget for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're after a free solution, have a look at Excel Package Plus: http://epplus.codeplex.com/

It should have all the features that you require.